The car rig bones are too big and I don't know how to scale them properly

Hello, I tried to rig my car by watching some videos, I re-named the wheels, body, I applied Scale and Rotation transformation, the car is facing -Y axis , I am using the fixed car rig addon and yet I don't know the root of the problem so I don't know what information would help.


Hello, if the problem is just the size, scale them down in Edit mode, but make sure that you don't change their origin location?

Hello, Can I scale rig bones? I scaled the wheels in edit mode

Yes in Edit mode, have your tried?

Okay this is stupid, @moonsboots just made me realize the rig bones origin's point is out of place, i set it to Origin to Geometry and my issue has been fixed.
